# How to make this code compatible for react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mern

In ProtectedRoute.js I have coded:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {!loading && (
          <Routes>
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) => {
            if (!isAuthenticated) {
              return <Navigate to="/login" />;
            }
            return <Component {...props} />;
          }}
        />
        </Routes>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

and in App.js I have written as:

```
function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      google: { families: ["Roboto", "Droid Sans", "Chilanka"] },
    });
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
        <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products />} />
        <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Authenticate />} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error says:  [ProtectedRoute] is not a Route component. All component children of Routes must be a Route or <React.Fragment>.

Is there something missing! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` custom route components are no longer used. `Routes` components can have only `Route` and `React.Fragment` components as children, and `Route` components can have only `Routes` or other `Route` components as a parent.

Instead wrapper components handle the business logic and either render the `children` prop or an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components, or the `Navigate` for redirection.

### Render `children`

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (loading) return null;

  return isAuthenticated
    ? children
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Route
  path="/account"
  element={(
    <ProtectedRoute>
      <Profile />
    </ProtectedRoute>
  )}
/>
```

### Render `Outlet`

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (loading) return null;

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Route path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
  <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
</Route>
```

The benefit of using the `Outlet` is you can use a single auth wrapper component and render any number of nested `Route` children into them, whereas with the `children` method you cannot render nested routes unless you wrap them in a `Routes` component.

Comment: Everytime I refresh the page it pushes to home page. What changes I can add so that when page is refreshed it stays on the same page ??

Comment: @MayankPandey Typically you use a loading or "pending" state to not commit to rendering the routed component or redirecting until the app is sure of any authentication states. What is the value of `loading` and `isAuthenticated` upon reloading the page/app?

Comment: If the user is logged in (isAuthenticated) it pushes the page to home page and loading is set to false.

Comment: @MayankPandey What is navigating to your home page `"/"`?

Comment: isAuthenticated

Comment: @MayankPandey Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding, but is `isAuthenticated` a boolean value? It isn't used as a function to invoke any navigation action to the home page. I'm asking what specifically is issuing a navigation to the `"/"` path? I.E. what is doing `navigate("/")` or rendering a `<Navigate to="/" />`?

Comment: if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate("/");
    }  This is the code which navigates to ("/")

Comment: @MayankPandey Why are you navigating to `"/"` is the user is authenticated? Should return the `children` prop or `Outlet` for nested routes.

Comment: Basically I wanted that if the user is authenticated he can not go to the login page again. Whenever he tries to go to login when authenticated he is navigated to Home page or "/"

Comment: @MayankPandey I see. For this then you'll want to create a sort of "Unprotected" wrapper component to render the `Login` component. The idea is the same as the protected route but in reverse, `return isAuthenticated ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : children;`, where children` is any component you don't want authenticated users to access, they get bounced to the home page `"/"`.

Answer (score -1):

How about flipping the logic around and checking everything inside ProtectedRoute like this?

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  
  if (loading) { return null; }

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return <Profile user={user} andWhateverElse={true} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And

```
function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      google: { families: ["Roboto", "Droid Sans", "Chilanka"] },
    });
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
        <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products />} />
        <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Authenticate />} />
        <Route exact path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```